# Setting page title after activation in Aurelia

Tags: config, router, aurelia, page-title

I am trying to set the title, however in this code below it works in one place and doesnt in other place. I want to get the product name and set the title. Is there any other way to do it?

```
activate(params: any, route, navigationInstruction) {       
        //route.navModel.router.title="test"; //works here
         this.api.pull<Product>([params.id]).then(items => {
                items.forEach(item=>
                {
                    if(item.id == params.id)
                        route.navModel.router.title = item.name //does NOT work here
                });

         });
    }
```

Comment: try `return this.api.pull`, looks like title is set after activate hook, so you have to set  `route.navModel.router.title` before activate hook finish execution

Comment: @valichek Thanks, Can you please add this to the answer, so I can mark it.

Comment: also, check my suggestion :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to return promise from api call, looks like page title is set after `activate` hook, so you have to set `route.navModel.router.title` before `activate` hook finishes execution

```
activate(params: any, route, navigationInstruction) {       
    //route.navModel.router.title="test"; //works here
     return this.api.pull<Product>([params.id]).then(items => {
            items.forEach(item=>
            {
                if(item.id == params.id)
                    route.navModel.router.title = item.name //does NOT work here
            });

     });
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Try using the `setTitle` method on the `NavModel`:

```
activate(params, routeConfig) {
  return this.api.pull<Product>([params.id]).then((items) => {
    let item = items.find((item) => item.id == params.id);
    if (item) {
        routeConfig.navModel.setTitle(item.name);
    }
  }
}
```

In the case above, you're pulling down a Product and then setting the page title to the item's name. In this use case, you'd likely want to set the `navModel` title. However, if you *really* want to change the `Router` title and not just the current navModel, you can do the following:

```
import { inject, Router } from 'aurelia-framework';

@inject(Router)
export class MyViewModel

    constructor(router) {
        this.router = router;
    }

    activate(params, routeConfig) {
      return this.api.pull<Product>([params.id]).then((items) => {
        let item = items.find((item) => item.id == params.id);
        if (item) {
            this.router.title = item.name;
            this.router.updateTitle();
        }
      }
    }
}
```

See more info in the [Router docs](http://aurelia.io/docs.html#/aurelia/framework/1.0.0-beta.1.2.4/doc/article/7).

Comment: This changes the NavModel Title. I am looking to change the router title. Thanks!

Comment: I've updated my answer, please check it and mark this as correct. :)

Comment: when I am getting route from the activate method, why should I inject the router object separately. can you please explain the advantage of doing it this way?

Comment: the first reason is that it is simply a best practice. anyone else reading your code will know exactly what you're doing and how you're doing it. the next, and possibly more compelling reason, is that `router` is not a property of `navModel` (see here: http://aurelia.io/docs.html#/aurelia/router/1.0.0-beta.1.2.2/doc/api/class/NavModel), and so you can't expect router to always be there.

Comment: please double check to see if this answer works for you, and accept and upvote it if so, thanks!

Comment: the accepted answer is not only misinformation, but the code is a straight copy / paste of the non-working code in the question

Comment: this.router does not have property named title. secondly, check this -> http://aurelia.io/docs.html#/aurelia/framework/1.0.0-beta.1.2.4/doc/article/cheat-sheet/7

Comment: yes, thats what I am using, the route parameter used in activate method. And there is no property called title for the router that is injected.

Comment: The documentation for the router has moved to here: http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/router/latest/router-configuration